# Spring cloud contract MockHttpServlet throwing illegal argument exception

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, mockmvc, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-contract

I'm using spring cloud contract to write tests for micro services which use eureka and ribbon.
 I'm able to generate the stubs and theyr'e deployed successfully but when i try to send a request to my consumer service, it throws an IllegalArgument exception. I tried adding headers but I'm still getting the same exception

This is my code

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(workOffline = true, ids = "com.example:example:+:stubs:8182")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

public class ExampleTest{
    static {
        System.setProperty("eureka.client.enabled", "false");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.failFast", "false");
        System.setProperty("stubrunner.cloud.ribbon.enabled", "false");
        System.setProperty("stubrunner.cloud.enabled", "false");
    }

    @Autowired MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testName() {
try {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/example_endpoint").header("host", "localhost:80")).andDo(print());
}
catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception i'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header value must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse.doAddHeaderValue(MockHttpServletResponse.java:570)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse.setHeaderValue(MockHttpServletResponse.java:543)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse.setHeader(MockHttpServletResponse.java:521)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:165)
at com.spectragrp.product.configuration.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:38)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:153)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
at com.spectragrp.product.restservice.EG.test1(EG.java:66)
at com.spectragrp.product.restservice.EG.testName(EG.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Can you please upload your code somewhere? Can you show what's happening in `com.spectragrp.product.configuration.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:38)`. Also can you post the whole logs in a GIST or sth?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Sorry, mistake was on our end. CORSFilter was setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `null` and that is why the calls were failing. We fixed it by providing the correct origin values in the call. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad you've managed to sort things out